# LibreOffice: horizontally align context of text box

Tags: libreoffice

How can I horizontally align the contents of a text box as e.g. "image" in the example below?'

If I select Center Horizontally (`Ctrl+E`) nothing happens and Format > Align displays checkmarks next to *both* Align Left (`Ctrl+L`) *and* Center Horizontally (`Ctrl+E`).

This is for LibreOffice Impress 5.1.6.2 on Ubuntu 16.04.03 LTS.

[image]

Comment: This kind of questions should rather be asked at [su].

Comment: On Libreoffice Writer 5.4.2.2 (Ubuntu 17.10) and in Calc Ctrl. + E seems to do what you want. The Libreoffice version you refer to (6.1.6.2) does not seem to exist yet.

Comment: @Bruni I mistyped the version number (now updated).

Comment: @rookie099 Unfortunately I do not have a 5.1.6.2 installed. However, the behavior is as expected on 5.4.2.2. I am inclined to think that this sounds like a bug....Maybe someone with 5.1.6.2 could confirm.

Comment: @Bruni +1 & thx for checking.